# How to get the keyword from this kind of String

Tags: javascript

I need to get the "payment type and the customer type from this kind of string

```
   Examples:
      |    D           | A  | B | C |
      |      NZ       | AAA           |     BBB    |      NZ       |
      |      AZ       | CCC           |    DDD        |  AZ  |
      |      CA      | EEE            |    FFF        |  CA  |
```

should I try the get the pattern and write a function for this? or I can find some library to detect it

so the output should be 
{payment:["AAA","CCC",'EEE'],
 customer:["BBB",'DDD","FFF"]}

```
function detect(str){
  let countBar=1
  let countBar2=0
  let paymentLoc=NaN
  let customerLoc=NaN
  let after =0
  let arr1=str.split(" ")
  arr1=arr1.filter(item=>{return item!==""})
  let newStr=''
  for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    arr1[i].trim()
    if(arr1[i]==='|'){
      countBar++
    }
    if(arr1[i]==="||"){
      countBar2++
    }
    if(arr1[i].includes("payment")){
      paymentLoc=i
    }

   after=((countBar/(countBar2))-1)*2
let sol=[]
  for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
  if(arr1[i].includes("payment")){
    console.log('payment index',i)
      sol.push(arr1[i+after+1])
    }
    if(arr1[i].includes("customer")){
      console.log('customer index',i)
      sol.push(arr1[i+after+1])
    }


  }


  newStr=arr1.join('')
  console.log(newStr)


}
```

Comment: Yes, write a function

Comment: I wrote it , but I think it's almost wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had some fun with this one. My first thought was to use an npm package, since the string looks a lot like CSV with `|` as the delimiter. The package [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) is a good one, but why use a well-regarded library when you can hack something together?

Here's my first attempt (in Typescript):

```
const exampleString = ` | market | payment type | customer type | translation |
                        | NZ     | AAA          | BBB           | NZ          |
                        | AZ     | CCC          | DDD           | AZ          |
                        | CA     | EEE          | FFF           | CA          |`;

const cleanColumn = (col: string) =>
  col
    .replace("|", "")
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s/, "_");

const cleanRow = (row: string) =>
  row
    .split(/\s\|/)
    .map(cleanColumn)
    .filter(Boolean);

const pivotRows = (
  pivoted: string[][],
  currentRow: string[],
  rowIndex: number
) => {
  if (rowIndex === 0) {
    currentRow.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
      pivoted[colIndex] = [col];
    });
  } else {
    currentRow.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
      pivoted[colIndex].push(col);
    });
  }

  return pivoted;
};

const buildObject = (
  obj: { [key: string]: string[] },
  currentRow: string[]
) => {
  let currentCol: string;

  currentRow.forEach((col, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      currentCol = col;

      obj[currentCol] = [];
    } else {
      obj[currentCol].push(col);
    }
  });

  return obj;
};

const detect = (str: string) =>
  str
    .split("\n")
    .map(cleanRow)
    .reduce(pivotRows, [])
    .reduce(buildObject, {});

console.log(detect(exampleString));
```

If you look at `detect`, it's just executing a series of functions on the string. The first one just splits it by line-breaks. I liked what you were going for with the `countBar` variables, but this seemed easier.

That gives us a bunch of string arrays, which need to be broken down into columns. Here, I used some RegEx to separate everything between a combination of `space` and `|`. In `cleanColumn()`, I remove the remaining `|`s in case there are any stragglers, then replace the spaces with underscores so they can be used as object keys.

Then, remove the empty strings with the `.filter(Boolean)` trick [(link)](http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array). The last two functions are probably more verbose than necessary, but they do the job. `pivotRows()` uses the row and column indexes to pivot columns into rows. Last, in `buildObject()` the first element of each of the rows is added as the key of an object, with the rest of the values being pushed into string arrays.

Really, you should probably just use `csvtojson`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at just splitting by |.

```
var text = `|    market     | payment type  | customer type |  translation  |
  |      NZ       | AAA           |     BBB    |      NZ       |
  |      AZ       | CCC           |    DDD        |  AZ  |
  |      CA      | EEE            |    FFF        |  CA  |`;

var result = {
    payment: text.split('|').filter((f, i) => i-7 >= 0 && (i - 7) % 5 == 0)
       .map(p => p.trim()),
    customer: text.split('|').filter((f, i) => i-8 >= 0 && (i - 8) % 5 == 0)
       .map(p => p.trim())
}

console.log(result)
```